# Why does the Commando 553 rifle's Tactical Stock mod give a -1 penalty to Concealment and give no bonuses?

Tags: payday-2

What causes the Tactical Stock mod for the Commando 553 rifle to show up as giving a -1 to the  Concealment stat and give no bonuses? Don't weapon mods (except sights) give at least 1 bonus to a weapon stat? This is the only non-sight weapon mod I've noticed that gives a penalty and doesn't give a bonus to a stat. Is this mod purely for aesthetics only?

[image: Tactical Stock mod for the Commando 553 rifle image]

A [post in the Reddit /r/paydaytheheist subreddit suggests that it increases a hidden stat](http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/1tszjd/why_does_my_tactical_stock_mod_for_the_commando/ceb6bwc). Can anyone confirm or deny?

In case it matters, my Commando 553 rifle also has the ff. mods equipped: Long Barrel, 'Fire Breather' barrel extension, 'Auto Fire' custom mod,  Enhanced Foregrip, 'Tactical Laser Module' gadget, Enhanced Grip, 'See More Sight', 'Heat Treated Body' upper receiver. I tried changing some of the mods, but it seems this does not affect the penalties of the Tactical Stock mod.

Comment: That's strange, tactical stocks for most of the other weapons give concealment at the cost of accuracy iirc...

Comment: I dont think every mod would at least give +1 to a weapon stat. I think I had this mod as well, but on a weapon I am using which already has maximum detection risk

Comment: @Loko Do you also get a -1 to Concealment with this mod? Does the mod give any weapon stat bonuses?

Comment: @galacticninja I've got it as -1 concealment as well. Let me test the differences between with and without the mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Recoil
>
> The base recoil is determined by (30-stability)/10. The allowed stability values are (12.5 and 17.5 shown as 12 and 17 in the inventory):
>   0, 3, 6, 8, 12.5, 15, 17.5, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
>
> Therefore a weapon with the maximum stability has a base recoil of 0.5, whereas a weapon with 0 stability has a base recoil of 3.
>
> The plateau at 20 stability means that you depending on your current index, using a weapon mod adding or subtracting 1 to the index may have no impact whatsoever. This plateau makes it rather easy to illustrate the mismatch between what mods claim to do and their actual effects. The Commando 553 without mods has a stability of 20 (the lower one). **Mods adding +1 to the stability index will still result in the same stability value, so the inventory does not state that such mods affects stability**. Mods increasing stability by more than +1 similarly show 1 less. If you have not attached any other mods to the gun, this is indeed what happens. However, the claimed effects of weapon mods do not consider already applied mods. If you have increased the stability index by +1 with other mods already, the stability will be increased by 1 for every further index shift of +1, though the individual mod keeps insisting that it increases stability by 1 less. Thus **adding the Tactical Stock**, which seems to do nothing but reduce concealment, **in fact adds +1 to the stability index**. Unmodded weapons with 20 stability are the only case where such latent effects exist, all due to this plateau. Damage, accuracy, etc. may not always give the right numbers, but they do always give something to quantify the actual effects.

Source:  The Long Guide
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=267214370

Answer (score 1):

I have this mod on my weapon as well and yes it gives me -1 concealment as well. I can't see any difference in shooting / looks in the first place etc.

With mod:

[image]

Without mod:

[image]

The only difference I can see is while reloading you can see the mod(which I think looks better than without the mod). Shooting didn't change. I think this is just for making it look better.